# React setState not updating state; callback not being called

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web-audio-api, setstate

I'm trying to take the metronome I built following the ["Tale of Two Clocks" tutorial](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/audio/scheduling/) and convert it into a simple React project. I figured it would be trivially easy to map the metronome's parameters (tempo, note divisions, etc.) and expand on it to build out a step sequencer (hooray for techno!). That said, I'm having trouble with a specific piece and I'm wondering why.

I've got pretty much all the salient pieces as state on the Metronome component, like so:

```
import React from 'react'

class Metronome extends React.Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props)

    this.audioContext = new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)()

    this.state = {
      tempo: 120.0,
      noteResolution: 0,
      isPlaying: false,
      current16thNote: 0,
      gateLength: 0.05,
      noteLength: 0.25,
      nextNoteTime: 0.0
    }

    this.lookahead = 0.1
    this.schedulerInterval = 25.0
    this.timerID = null

    this.updateStartStopText = this.updateStartStopText.bind(this)
    this.play = this.play.bind(this)
    this.scheduler = this.scheduler.bind(this)
    this.scheduleNote = this.scheduleNote.bind(this)
    this.nextNote = this.nextNote.bind(this)
  }

  updateStartStopText () {
    return this.state.isPlaying ? 'Stop' : 'Start'
  }

  play () {
    this.setState({ isPlaying: !this.state.isPlaying }, () => {
      if (this.state.isPlaying) {
        this.setState({ current16thNote: 0 }, () => {
          this.setState({
            nextNoteTime: this.audioContext.currentTime
          }, this.scheduler)
        })
      } else {
        window.clearTimeout(this.timerID)
      }
    })
  }

  scheduler () {
    while (this.state.nextNoteTime < this.audioContext.currentTime + this.lookahead) {
      this.scheduleNote(this.state.current16thNote, this.state.nextNoteTime)
      this.nextNote()
    }

    this.timerID = window.setTimeout(this.scheduler, this.schedulerInterval)
  }

  scheduleNote (beatNumber, time) {
    if ((this.state.noteResolution === 1) && (beatNumber % 2)) {
      return
    } else if ((this.state.noteResolution === 2) && (beatNumber % 4)) {
      return
    }
    const osc = this.audioContext.createOscillator()
    osc.connect(this.audioContext.destination)
    if (!(beatNumber % 16)) {
      osc.frequency.value = 220
    } else if (beatNumber % 4) {
      osc.frequency.value = 440
    } else {
      osc.frequency.value = 880
    }

    osc.start(time)
    osc.stop(time + this.state.gateLength)
  }

  nextNote () {
    var secondsPerBeat = 60.0 / this.state.tempo
    let nextTime = this.state.nextNoteTime + (secondsPerBeat * this.state.noteLength)

    this.setState({
      nextNoteTime: nextTime,
      current16thNote: (this.state.current16thNote + 1)
    }, () => {
      if (this.state.current16thNote === 16) {
        this.setState({ current16thNote: 0 })
      }
    })
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <div>
        Metronome

        <button type='button' onClick={this.play}>{this.updateStartStopText()}</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Metronome
```

More or less everything plays out like you'd expect from React, swapping out vanilla JS variable reassignment/incrementing with `this.setState()` calls, . There are quite a few situations where I need to do calculations with an updated value in state and, knowing that `setState()` is asynchronous and often batches calls, I rely somewhat heavily on the optional callback that setState takes.

The one place where things seem to be going awry is in the `nextNote()` method. The state never updates properly: `this.state.nextNoteTime` never gets an updated value beyond that which it is assigned in the `play()` method The code as it is will never get into the callback passed to `setState()` called from `nextNote()`. If I remove `nextNoteTime` from the component's state and save it as a property on the component, manually updating and tracking its value, the metronome seems to work as expected, à la the end state of my metronome in vanilla JS. Technically a success, but not the answer I'm looking for.

I tried using Promises and I tried using the React Component API (`componentWillUpdate`, `shouldComponentUpdate`, etc.) to figure out whether or not the next state is the one I'm looking for. But beyond a certain point (like 3 recursive calls of the `scheduler()` method), the while loop goes haywire since this.state.nextNoteTime never increases. Gah!

Thoughts?

Comment: I predict functional setState fixes this https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate `this.setState((prevState, props) => {`

Comment: Are you sure that `nextNote()` is getting called at all?

Comment: @azium I have tried that, with no luck; I'll give it another shot; there's a chance I wasn't getting the syntax correctly the first time around.

Comment: @jered `nextNote()` is most certainly being called. over and over and over and over and over again.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because you have nested `setState`s.

Try below as play method.

```
play() {
  const { isPlaying } = this.state;
  const newState = { isPlaying: !isPlaying };
  if (!isPlaying) {
    Object.assign(newState, {
      current16thNote: 0,
      nextNoteTime: this.audioContext.currentTime
    });
  }

  this.setState(newState, (...args) => {
    if (!isPlaying) {
      this.scheduler(...args);
    } else {
      window.clearTimeout(this.timerID)
    }
  });
}
```

Remove `setState` nesting for `nextNote` as well.

Comment: Just did that; no luck. That call to `setState` in `nextNote()` never seems to fire correctly since `componentDidUpdate` doesn't get called more than once.